# CAS server error

Tags: java, spring, cas

Im gettin this error whe i run the cas-overlay

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forRawClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/springframework/core/ResolvableType;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:415)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:530)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.jasig.cas.web.init.SafeContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(SafeContextLoaderListener.java:75)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:5362)
```

this is my pom

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd ">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId>
    <artifactId>cas-overlay</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.rimerosolutions.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wrapper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.4</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warName>cas</warName>
                    <overlays>
                        <overlay>
                            <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId>
                            <artifactId>cas-server-webapp</artifactId>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>WEB-INF/cas.properties</exclude>
                                <exclude>WEB-INF/classes/log4j2.xml</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </overlay>
                    </overlays>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-jetty-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <jettyXml>${basedir}/etc/jetty/jetty.xml,${basedir}/etc/jetty/jetty-ssl.xml,${basedir}/etc/jetty/jetty-https.xml</jettyXml>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <systemProperty>
                            <name>org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.maxWait</name>
                            <value>240</value>
                        </systemProperty>
                    </systemProperties>
                    <webApp>
                        <contextPath>/cas</contextPath>
                        <overrideDescriptor>${basedir}/etc/jetty/web.xml</overrideDescriptor>
                    </webApp>
                    <webAppConfig>
                        <allowDuplicateFragmentNames>true</allowDuplicateFragmentNames>
                    </webAppConfig>
                    <jvmArgs>-Dlog4j.configurationFile=/etc/cas/log4j2.xml -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=5000,server=y,suspend=n</jvmArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>cas</finalName>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId>
            <artifactId>cas-server-webapp</artifactId>
            <version>${cas.version}</version>
            <type>war</type>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId>
            <artifactId>cas-server-webapp-support</artifactId>
            <version>${cas.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId>
            <artifactId>cas-server-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- jdbc oracle -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId>
            <artifactId>cas-server-support-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${cas.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.perf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>perf4j</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.16</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>            
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <cas.version>4.2.3</cas.version>
        <spring.version>4.2.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <maven-jetty-plugin.version>9.3.6.v20151106</maven-jetty-plugin.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype-releases</id>
            <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype-snapshots</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple Spring jars inside Web-INF/lib. Examine which is the conflict and remove/exclude it from your dependencies.